# "q&a" link at the very bottom of the SE chat FAQ goes to stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, chat

I guess this is an oversight. That link is probably best deleted, or maybe changed to:

> [report bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug+chat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it pointed to SE which isn't really a Q&A site was an oversight, but upon review the link itself is redundant since there is always a link in the header bar. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Q&A stands for Questions and Answers. The link directs you to the lobby hub of Stack Exchange, built on Q&A.

The Stack Exchange homepage displays the so-hot-right-now questions which have answers.

The oversight here is that chat itself is not enough of a black hole of despair.

Comment: To be honest the real problem is I don't know why that link is there to begin with. Linking to StackExchange.com probably isn't it, though.